# Playing sound files in an iOS app

Tags: ios

I am making an app that plays sound files based on choices from a view controller. I have a view controller that will pop up and it displays a view with a city name, description, picture and a button that should play a simple sound. In the example below, it will play a sound file named "slang4." This is the code for my button in the implementation file:

```
- (IBAction)soundButton:(id)sender{ 


    CFBundleRef mainBundle=CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef=CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"slang4", CFSTR("mp3"),NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

The problem is that I want the button to play different sounds depending on the choices from the original view controller (a list of cities).

For example, my code below from my app delegate implementation file shows how each city has a different sound file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    City *london = [[City alloc]init];
    london.cityName = @"London";
    london.cityDescription = @"The cap of UK.";
    london.cityPicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"London.jpg"];
    london.soundFile=@"slang4.mp3";

    City *sanFranciso = [[City alloc]init];
    sanFranciso.cityName = @"San Francisco";
    sanFranciso.cityDescription=@"City by the Bay";
    sanFranciso.cityPicture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SanFranciso.jpg"];
    sanFranciso.soundFile=@"babymama.mp3";
```

My problem is that I want the button to be able to know which soundFile to play based on the city. I've been teaching myself iOS programming for about 8 months, but I still am quiet the beginner. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So there's a number of steps here, where are you stuck?

Comment: Here's where I'm stuck: when I click on a city in my view controller, I go to my next view controller that shows a city with a description and a picture. There's also a button on  that second view controller that should play a short sound file. That's where I'm stuck. I want the button to play the soundFile file that i created for London when I"m on the London view and then when I go to the San Francisco view, I want the button to play the sound file I have for that view. Each city is part of an array of cities and I can't seem to access the sound files that are part of that array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your view controller already has a `City` property on it, so in your button action you should be able to use the sound file from the `soundFile` property. Use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of `NSString` to separate into name and extension. I think you could also just pass the full file name itself and `NULL` as the extension. This solution assumes ARC.

```
NSArray *soundFileComponents = [self.city.soundFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([soundFileComponents count] == 2) {
    NSString *fileName = soundFileComponents[0];
    NSString *fileExtension = soundFileComponents[1];
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    if (mainBundle) {
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileName, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension, NULL);
        if (soundFileURLRef) {
            UInt32 soundID;
            OSStatus resultCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
            if (resultCode == kAudioServicesNoError) {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"error creating system sound ID: %ld", resultCode);
            }
            CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error loading sound file URL");
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error loading main bundle");
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"error splitting filename into name and extension");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. When I tried this I have three error messages. For the first line, it says "Property 'City' not found on object of type 'CityController.' On the third and fourth lines (beginning with NSString) the message is:Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray' which is not constant in non-fragile ABI.

Comment: @user2208602 I made an assumption that since you have a view controller "that shows a city with a description and a picture" that the view controller would also have a property named `city` of type `City`. Replace `self.city` in this code with however you reference your `City` instance variable in your view controller. Regarding the other errors, are you using an older version of Xcode (or otherwise not using a modern version of the clang compiler)? If so replace them with [soundFileComponents objectAtIndex:(0 or 1 here)]. Also, you're welcome, I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Carl, I'm getting close here...I only have one error message now. In my CGAppDelegate.m file, here is how I made the cities:

Comment: Sorry, I hit return before finishing....
    
    self.cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:london,sanFranciso,sydney,madrid, nil];

Comment: So I assumed that I could replace City with cities, but no matter what i put for the name, the program keeps saying that it's property is not found on object of type cityController. I thought that by including the file at the top, it would recognize it, but it's not. I've tried including all my files at top, but it still won't recognize it. I'm using Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: @user2208602 As I said - replace `self.city` in my code with however you reference the city in your city controller. You're displaying text and images about it, as you say. So how are you referring to a `City` to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this! Somehow I'm referring to it in my viewDidLoad:

Comment: Like this:[super viewDidLoad];
    CGAppDelegate *delegate=
    (CGAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    City *thisCity=[delegate.cities objectAtIndex:index.row];
    self.title = thisCity.cityName;
    descriptionView.text=thisCity.cityDescription;
    descriptionView.editable=NO;
    pictureView.image=thisCity.cityPicture;
but in my interface I only have: 
    NSIndexPath *index;
   
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pictureView;
    IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionView;
    
I tried creating an NSString to refer to, but my button doesn't seem to be able to see it.

Comment: Add a property to your class, `city`, with `@property (nonatomic, strong) City *city;`, then in your `viewDidLoad` do `self.city = thisCity;`. Seems easier to just pass the city controller the city directly when it's instantiated but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: Do I add the @property code in the  city.h file? Somehow my city view controller just isn't seeing it.

Comment: Your view controller is called `CityController`, right? So you probably have `CityController.h`. So in there you probably have `@interface CityController : UIViewController { ... some ivars ... } ... some properties and public methods ... @end`. Put it outside of the curly braces, but between the `@interface... `and `@end`. You're using a pretty old version of Xcode you may need to synthesize those properties too (or even better upgrade), look up how to declare and synthesize a property it's pretty straightforward if a bit long winded. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your patience and help with this. I made the changes you suggested and I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode. The last errors I had are now gone, but it crashes each time saying I have duplicate 7 duplicate symbols. I don't see any duplicates. Perhaps I need to start from scratch (once again). I've been working through a book "Learning IOS Programming"  (O'Reilly). I've been through every book I can find in the bookstores and yet I'm still struggling. I used to program some in C++, but this Objective C doesn't come naturally to me. But I'm not giving up.

Comment: It crashes? Usually a duplicate symbols is a linker failure. You probably added variables with the same name in areas that have global scope, i.e. outside of an `@interface` or `@implementation` block. I highly recommend you to read Apple's guides on various subjects and take the time to read and understand the source code in their sample projects. Reading and writing actual working code and getting familiar with the documentation will help you far more than copying things out of a book that may steer you wrong anyway.

Comment: @user2208602 had any luck?

Comment: Thanks for checking, Carl. I haven't been able to get through it. I've started re-reading all the basic apple documentation, hoping I'll catch a clue. It seems like this app I'm doing aught to be simple enough---to have  a list that can drill down to a view with a label and a button, a button that can play an array of simple sound files, but that part is just not coming together for me. I keep looking for sample code for something that does the same, but I can't find it. I'm not sure why upgrading my Xcode gave me that new set of errors. I'm patient and persistent. Sooner or later, I'll know.